# R animation with animation package+html

Tags: r, animation

I am aware there is plenty of content on this topic but after extensive research I could not quite find what I was after.
I am new to R animation and have recently installed the animation package with which I managed to create a simple animated dot plot on a web browser after using this code containing a basic loop:

```
n = 20
x = sort(rnorm(n))
y = rnorm(n)
par(bg = "white")
plot(x, y, type = "n")
ani.record(reset = TRUE)

for (i in 1:n) {
points(x[i], y[i], pch = 19, cex = 2)
ani.record() # record the current frame
}

oopts = ani.options(interval = 0.5)
ani.replay()
saveHTML(ani.replay(), img.name = "record_plot")
```

This generated different folders (css, images and js) as well as a web browser shortcut on my desktop redirecting to the web page where this animation can be played. Dropping these folders on any other desktop will allow to play the same animation anywhere. Problem: I have different png files generated with R and containing geom_point() plot on 2 axes over different time periods. I would like to achieve with the same technique above described the same result with a loop over the correspondent month from each of these png files, similarly to what can be seen here: http://www.ggplot2-exts.org/gganimate.html. Is there any way to achieve this result without having to install any additional software?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand. Is it what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)
library(animation)

years <- unique(gapminder$year)
saveHTML({
  for(year in years){
    dat <- gapminder[gapminder$year==year,]
    gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_log10() +
      ggtitle(year)
    print(gg)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane. Not exactly but quite. In my understanding (but I might be wrong) your code is adding a gapminder library and reading data from a preset data source. I would like to achieve similar results but using my data which I produced separately with R ggplot. Is there a way to animate my data either via png files or through the original R codes I used to produce these png files (basically 4 plots over 4 different months)? Thanks

Comment: @user8961931 I load the `gapminder` library just to have the `gapminder` dataframe for my example. Replace `gg <- ggplot ....` with your code. Otherwise I don't understand, it would be clearer if you post your data (or a piece).

Comment: I made huge progresses with your simple suggestion. Thank you Stephane. This is my short-code I used on the basis of your previous message:
months <- unique(zed$TIMECONSTRAINT)
saveHTML({
  for(TIMECONSTRAINT in months){
    dat <- zed[zed$TIMECONSTRAINT==TIMECONSTRAINT,]
    gg <- ggplot(data=zed, aes(x=K_DEPUSD,y=TRX_COUNT, label=CURRENCY)) + 
geom_point(alpha=0.7, aes(fill=CURRENCY, size=TRX_COUNT),pch=21) +  
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10)))+
labs(color="Currency", size="TRX Count") +
scale_x_log10() 
    print(gg)
  }
}) How can I make this data live?

Comment: Apologies for the format of the above. I had few characters left. I would like to see animation of data based on TIMECONSTRAINT column which is a value containing four different time frames..

Comment: @user8961931And this code does not generate the desired animation? It should. What is the problem?

Comment: This code shows a single image over and over without actually looping through TIMECONSTRAINT: the images folder has 4 png files with the same image. The manual solution would be to add new png files in the images folder and possibly re-calibrate the intervals between images. The first minor problem I encountered in this approach was the size of the manually added png files which is too large compared to the rest. Stephane you really helped me and even though you will not reply I sincerely thank you for your precious help..

Comment: @user8961931I see the error in your code: replace `ggplot(data=zed` with `ggplot(data=dat` ! If I was helpful you can upvote my answer and click the checkmark if the problem is solved :)

Comment: You are a star. I am quite a new joiner, and have upvoted your answer but being a new joiner have little privileges and my vote has not been made public. Be well!